# Precision issue in normal distributions - Graphics Calculators and R Calculations

Tags: r, self-study, normal-distribution

I am using R for make some stuff of normal distribution calculation for test some examples that use Texas Instruments TI-83 Plus Graphing Calculator (thats looks like and ad)

I dont have it and i dont care i can do it with python and R but i find this:

[image]

So advanced graphic calculator are better than programming languages or is only numeric errors?

Comment: This programming-only question belongs on [SO], but you are blocked from posting there.  Please don't use CV as a way of circumventing that issue. -1.

Comment: I see no discrepancies that amount to errors. R usually gives more decimal places than would ever be relevant in practice. // I'm not saying the extra decimal places from TI-83 are wrong. only that they are largely irrelevant. // Consider this experiment. I averaged a sample of size ten million from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100, \sigma=15)$ and got   $99.99941$ instead of $100.$ If you can't tell the difference in a sample of ten million, is the fifth decimal place of practical importance.

Comment: @Bruce Sometimes the precision matters, such when working with truncated Normals or computing anything related to tail probabilities.  More to the point, perhaps, is that no double-precision implementation of `pnorm` makes an effort to compute more than about 16 decimal digits (and often only just 12 or so) because it is necessarily an approximation.

Comment: I am not trying to circunavigate or whatever you all(-1)think. This question can improve CV. and this issue not was a big problem for me. i ask here after solving that exercise. [i read this before post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65623/which-site-is-more-reasonable-for-questions-about-r-so-or-stats-stackexchange-c)

and explain me how high precision for make better STATS calculation is related to programming?

i have no problem with the downvotes and his inquisitors stacks mods i only interested in the Q/A and if cant find the answers i post my own after research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Controlling number of decimal digits in print output in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-number-of-decimal-digits-in-print-output-in-r), for example.

R calculates in higher precision, it just doesn't print an excess number of digits by default. [image]

Comment: How can I put sprintf() as default print or how can i have more decimals as default?. do you know? @Ron Jensen

Comment: Try options("digits"=7) where the number is the number of significant figures. Look at help(options) for more details

Comment: @rubengavidia0x you can also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11228403/setting-default-number-of-decimal-places-for-printing